# "function: not found" error under Termux sh

Tags: android, shell, termux

After starting script testyon.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh 
function yon { 
while true; do 
echo "Start proc?[Y/n]: "
read -r "[Y/n]: " yn 
case $yn in 
[Yy]*) echo "Starting" ; return 0 ;;
[Nn]*) echo "Stopped" ; return 1 ;; 
esac 
done }
```

I am getting this error:

> ```
> $ sh testyon.sh
> testyon.sh: 2: testyon.sh: function: not found
> testyon.sh: 7: testyon.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
> $
> ```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess whatever shell is run when you call `sh` is thrown off by the function syntax. The portable way of declaring a function is

```
yon() { 
    while true; do 
        echo "Start proc?[Y/n]: "
        read -r "[Y/n]: " yn 
        case $yn in 
            [Yy]*) echo "Starting"; return 0 ;;
            [Nn]*) echo "Stopped"; return 1 ;; 
        esac 
    done
}
```

Reference: POSIX spec, Shell Command Language, [Function Definition Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

Two remarks:

- You seem to prompt the user twice, but I'm not sure if the prompt in the `read -r` command does anything at all. It actually seems to prevent reading anything into `yn` in the first place.
- Termux comes with a full blown Bash living at `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash`, which would prevent your function problem.

Comment: I think we can fairly certain that the *whatever shell* indeed **is** POSIX shell. If the OP would explicitly invoke it as, say, bash or Zsh, the wording of the error message would be different.